# Qt ActiveX dynamicCall return value always empty

Tags: c++, qt, activex, qstring, bstr

This is a follow up to a previous question: [Qt ActiveX](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-13845?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel)

I am trying to use an ActiveX control in my program.

```
QAxWidget* mAX = new QAxWidget();
mAX->setControl("{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}");
```

I know that there is a function like the one below (used `getDocumentation()`):

```
SendCommand(QString input, QString& output)
```

But when I try to execute it:

```
QString returString;
mAX->dynamicCall("SendCommand(QString,QString&)","something",returnString);
```

I always get:

```
returString = "";
```

I searched the web and saw a similar bug which was reported on their bug tracker. It does not seem fixed yet:

[Calling functions through dynamicCall() don't return values by QVariant](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-13845?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel)

Also a post where someone seems to have the same problem:

[QAxObject and dynamicCall](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/9957)

Anybody know of a solution/work around ?

EDIT:

The original function is `SendCommand(LPCTSTR command,BSTR* ret)`.

Maybe an issue with the way the `BSTR*` is handled as a `&QString` ?

Answer (score 3):

you can use this solution

```
QString strRetVal;
QVariant returnValue("");
QVariant param1("something");
QList<QVariant> inplist;
inplist<<param1;
inplist<<returnValue;
mAX->dynamicCall("SendCommand(QString,QString&)",inplist );
strRetVal=inplist.at(1).toString();
```

Comment: Why pack the parameters into inplist and unpack them?  I see that it works better, but I don't understand why.  I tried @thomas solution above, but the return string value isn't set.  When the values are packed into inplist, dynamicCall can set QString values, but not QStringList values.  QStringList values still don't get set, and I get an error msg "QAxBase: Error calling IDispatch member GetPorts: Unknown error"

Answer (score 2):

From looking at the [documentation](http://doc.qt.digia.com/stable/qaxbase.html), you are not calling the function correctly. You are passing in  a `QString`, yet the function takes a `QVariant`. Since `QVariant` doesn't have explicit constructors (by design), a temporary QVariant is created and passed to `dynamicCall`. As a consequence your `returnValue` doesn't get updated.

```
QVariant dynamicCall( const char * function, const QVariant & var1 = QVariant(), ...
                    , const QVariant & var8 = QVariant() )
```

I think that everything will work when you use a QVariant instead.

```
 QVariant returnValue;
 mAX->dynamicCall("SendCommand(QString,QString&)", "something", returnValue );
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it does not work. I already tried it.